# Bootstrap modal showing multiple times

Tags: c#, jquery, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have a .NET application using C#, Bootstrap 2.3.2 and the latest version of jQuery. 
In my Javascript file, I show a Modal everytime the user clicks a button, by making an Ajax request to the server which then returns the HTML for the modal with all the information:

Sounds complex, but in reality is quite simple.

This is the CSHTML file:

```
//div for the EditPackage modal
<div id="editModal"></div>
```

This is the JavaScript that shows the modal:

```
//Show Edit Package modal
    $("a.btn.btn-default.editPackage").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: $(this).data('url'),
            type: 'get',
            cache: false,
            success: function (result) {
                $('#editModal').html(result).find('.modal').modal({
                    show: true
                });

            //the popup needs these files to work 
            //so we send them over the internet to the client !
            dyamicallyLoadJS("Scripts/myCustom.js");
            }
        });
        return false; //prevent browser defualt behavior
    });
```

So, when I click the said button, the server receives the request, and sends me the HTML with the modal code, which then is placed inside the `editModal` div, which then is shown to the user.

The dynamic loading of the Javascript needed by the Modal is done by a function in the same file:

```
//http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss.shtml
function dyamicallyLoadJS(filePath) {
    var fileref = document.createElement('script');
    fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
    fileref.setAttribute("src", filePath);
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref)
}
```

The Modal itself is just plain HTML. It is quite boring:

```
@model AmarisGate.Model.ModalPackageInfo

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "_ModalPackageInfo";
}

<div class="modal fade" id="@Model.modalId" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="@Model.modalId" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" style="overflow-y: auto; max-height: 80vh;">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">@Model.modalTitle</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" data-val="@Model.packageId">
                <form class="form-horizontal">
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Package Name: </label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="package-name" placeholder="@Model.pkgNamePlaceHolder">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Select the Function:</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input class="select2s" data-edit-values="@Model.functionsString" data-o2f-placeholder="Select Employee Function..." data-o2f-url="@Url.Action("FunctionsMultiple", "Home")" data-val="false" id="SubCategoryId" name="SubCategoryId" multiple="multiple" type="text"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Select the materials:</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input class="select2s" data-edit-values="@Model.materialsString" data-o2f-placeholder="Select Materials..." data-o2f-url="@Url.Action("MaterialsMultiple", "Home")" data-val="false" id="MaterialId" name="MaterialId" multiple="multiple" type="text" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Company:</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input class="select2s" data-edit-values="@Model.companiesString" data-o2f-placeholder="All Companies (default)" data-o2f-url="@Url.Action("CompaniesMultiple", "Home")" data-val="false" id="CompaniesId" name="CompaniesId" multiple="multiple" type="text" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="@Model.saveButtonId" data-url="@Model.saveButtonUrl">@Model.saveButtonText</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

However, I have a problem. If I click the button once, the popup shows once, which is quite fine. If I click it twice, it shows twice, which is annoying. If I click it X times, it appears X times, which is simply terrible.

From my understanding, this bug occurs because each time I click the Edit button, I send and load a Javascript file. Then the next time I click the button, I will run the previous file that I got, plus the new one, and so on.

How do I fix this?
How do I keep the JavaScript files from being run multiple times?

Comment: Are causing a post back, or are you using the JQuery Get command?  Please show the script that loads the data ind the editModal div.

Comment: Are you returning scripts in the response that may also contain modal init?

Comment: Added a lot of information. I know what the bug is, and I know why it happens, but I just have no idea if it is even possible to fix it :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to the bug:

- Make sure the content in `MyCustom.js` is **not** being loaded by the main page either. In short, its contents should be unique and for the Modal only!